# Angular 5, Please tell me List of types supported by ngx formly in FormlyFieldConfig

Tags: angular, angular-formly

This question is related to ngx formly and Angular 5
 here type is input. I want to know List of types
 supported by ngx formly in FormlyFieldConfig
I have the below code

```
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model = { email: 'email@gmail.com' };
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
    key: 'email',
    type: 'input',  // here type is input. I want to know List of types
 // supported by ngx formly in FormlyFieldConfig

    templateOptions: {
      type: 'email',
      label: 'Email address',
      placeholder: 'Enter email',
      required: true,
    }
  },
  {
    key: 'email',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      type: 'email',
      label: 'Email address',
      placeholder: 'Enter email',
      required: true,
    }
  }



];

  submit(model) {
    console.log(model);
  }
}
```

here type is input. I want to know List of types
 supported by ngx formly in FormlyFieldConfig

Answer (score 3):

You can see a list of all supported types for each framework you can use with ngx-formly on:

https://formly.dev/ui

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which template you are using. If you look at [Material Design](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/tree/master/src/ui-material/src/types), you will see that it includes checkbox, input, multicheckbox, radio, select, and textarea. If you look at [Kendo](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/tree/master/src/ui-kendo/src/types), you will see that it includes checkbox, input, radio, select, and textarea.